# Performance enhancement for my normalization code

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning

I am working on an LSTM network, it predicts stock prices.
I am normalizing about 270mb of data. Which results in about 1.3 Million lines that need normalization.

This code is quite slow. I am running it on my computer for 64 hours straight and it has still not finished.

I am quite new to Python so I do know how to write it, but I don't know how to optimize it. I also have no idea what is the slowest part of this code.

`model_data` is a pandas dataframe.

```
norm_cols = ['close_price'] + ['engagement'] + ['volume']
window_len = 64
pred_range = 6

def normalize(model_data,norm_cols,window_len,pred_range):
    LSTM_training_inputs = []
    LSTM_training_outputs = []

    for i in range(len(model_data)-window_len-pred_range):
        temp_set = model_data[i:(i+window_len)].copy()
        for col in norm_cols:
            temp_set.loc[:, col] = model_data[col]/model_data[col].iloc[0] - 1
        LSTM_training_inputs.append(temp_set)
    for i in range(window_len, len(model_data['close_price'])-pred_range):
        LSTM_training_outputs.append((model_data['close_price'][i:i+pred_range].values/
                                    model_data['close_price'].values[i-window_len])-1)
    return [LSTM_training_inputs,LSTM_training_outputs]
```

Comment: What sort of normalization are you doing?

Comment: Which part is the slow one? The first loop, the second one, or both equally?

Comment: I divide the values of the window by the first value in the window and subtract one. Very basic normalization but for now it's good enough.

Comment: The first loop is the slowest. But both could use some optimization.

Comment: Are you running your ML architecture on GPU? If so, you could write the normalization operation as part of your neural net. Otherwise, you can convert your lists to numpy arrays and run the normalization as vectorized operations (per-batch).

Comment: I am running my ML architecture on GPU but this normalization happens before that. I will look into doing it as a part of my NN. Also per batch is also something I didn't think of. Thank you!